# Custom URL rewrite rule in Blazor ASP.Net Core (server-side) not triggering when using navlink

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following `IRule` set up in my solution:

```
public class IsUrlEncodedRule : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var host = request.Host;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
    }
}
```

And then in my `Startup.cs` I have the following...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new IsUrlEncodedRule()));  
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    ...

    app.UseMvc();

    ...

}
```

Eventually I want the rule to check that any URLs are encoded but for now I just want to see the "Hello world" in the console to know that its working, or for it to hit my breakpoints in the rule at all. This is a server-side blazor app and right now the only time the rule is hit is when you initially navigate to the site or if you manually navigate to a particular page of the site by typing the url in the nav bar in the browser and navigating manually. If, however, you use a `NavLink` to navigate within the site, the rule is never triggered since the client is never making any additional requests since its all handled through SignalR.

Example:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="s3contents">
    <span class="fas fa-bold" aria-hidden="true"></span> S3 Contents
</NavLink>
```

If you are *already* on the website, clicking this `NavLink` will take you to `http://localhost:8080/s3contents` and the rule will ***not*** be triggered. Once you are there, if you refresh the page manually or if you copy the URL and paste it into a new tab and navigate to it, the rule ***will*** be triggered. My question is how do I configure my services such that any `IRule` I implement will *always* be triggered even if a particular page was navigated to by a user *already* on the website and therefor navigating via SignalR instead of a traditional http request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url rewrite rewite the url in the server when a http request is received.
Navigation through SignalR do not make http request so you cannot use URL rewritting for your behavior.

But if the goal is to capture each navigation event, Use [`NavigationManager.LocationChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.locationchanged?view=aspnetcore-3.0). It's not cancellable at the moment, and we cannot prevent navigation. But an issue is open https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14962

Comment: Ah I see, looks like they want to add it themselves at some point. Thanks for the link to the active issue.