# Redirecting in Asp.Net Core Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, blazor, middleware

I'm attempting to learn how to perform redirects/rewrites in a Asp.NET Core app and I am following this article: [Back to Basics: Rewriting a URL in ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Mar/13/Back-to-Basics-Rewriting-a-URL-in-ASPNET-Core). However, when I attempt the example for "Re-writing a URL" section, I only see the main "/Index" page and not the "/TargetPage".

I can browse to the "/TargetPage" manually and it will render but it is not done automatically. I'm attempting this method of rewrite/redirect based upon "flags" that will be set in the "appSettings.json" file of the program.

This is the code for the "Startup.cs" file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        string url = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (!url.Contains("/TargetPage") && AppSettings.SendUserToTargetPage == true)
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/TargetPage";
        }

        await next();
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
}
```

This is the code for the "_Host.cshtml" file:

```
@page "/"
@namespace MyTestApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            
        <title>My Test Redirect</title>
            
        <base href="~/" />
            
        <link href="~/Styles/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code for the "/Index" page:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
```

This is the code for the "/TargetPage":

```
@page "/TargetPage"

<h3>The page I'm trying to get to.</h3>
```

Once the app is started, I arrive at the root "/" page (localhost:#some_port_number) where "Hello, world!" is displayed and the URL never arrives "/TargetPage" as I expect it to.

Is there something specific I am missing or have misconfigured? This example is being done in .NET 5 at the moment (if that has any bearing at all).

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware is for Razor Pages / MVC applications. Blazor has no concept of an HTTP Request pipeline, therefore there is no middleware.

In the case of Blazor WASM, the app is loaded into the browser and code executes in the browser.

In your case of Blazor Server, the app is run on the server, and rendered updates are pushed over a SignalR connection.

> See: [Custom URL rewrite rule in Blazor ASP.Net Core (server-side) not triggering when using navlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182560/custom-url-rewrite-rule-in-blazor-asp-net-core-server-side-not-triggering-when)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I'll instead just opt to do these redirect checks inside of the "MainLayout.razor" using the "OnInitialized" method to check the appSettings and rewrite/redirect as needed. At least that method will work for my use case.